# Python - line break after each item in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

I have an empty list and a loop. The loop's results append to the empty list. The list is then emailed to me but it comes in the form of `['item1', 'item2]` I would like this list to be formatted like so:

```
item1
item2
```

My code looks something like this:

```
list = []

def function_name():
    for item in items:
        r = requests.get(item)
        results = r.status_code, r.url
        print(results, time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        for s_code in results:
            list.append(s_code)

    msg = str(list)
    subject = 'Hello'
    sender = 'me@example.com'
    recepient = 'you@example.com'

    s = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
    s.sendmail('address1@example.com', 'address2@example.com', msg)
    s.quit()
```

check_broken_links()

When I remove `str` and do `msg = '\n'.join(list)` I get an error because I am combining `int` and `str` as seen in this line `results = r.status_code, r.url` leaving `str` returns every iterable in one line, so that's no good either.

ps
still working on my mail function, it's a bit sloppy, but it sends.

Comment: You could use another loop and print each item.

Comment: What is the code that actually e-mails the list? It should append the contents of the list to the e-mail one item at a time, not simply covert the list to a string.

Comment: Or use [**`str.join`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join): `'\n'.join(codes)`

Comment: You need to show the rest of your code.

Comment: Edited question to show all of the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the `str.join` on a list of numbers, run a list comprehension to convert:

```
msg = '\n'.join([str(i) for i in list])
```

Comment: This seemed to do the trick. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

When you build the text for the email, convert the list to a string with newlines like this

```
text = '\n'.join(list)
```

If you're sending an html email, you may have to do this

```
text = '<br/>'.join(list)
```

Comment: For the HTML version, it should actually be `'<br>'.join(map(cgi.escape, my_list))`.

Comment: I just added all my code to make the scenario more clear